# types.MethodType and the for loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to use types.MethodType to modify the behaviour of some iterator.

```
def parse(line):
    return line.upper()

def reader(f):
    f.__next__ = types.MethodType(lambda x: parse(_io.TextIOWrapper.readline(x)), f)
    f.__iter__ = types.MethodType(lambda x: x, f)
    return f
```

I guess I'm using types.MethodType correctly, because running the following code I get the expected result:

```
>>with open("myfile.txt") as f:
>>    x = reader(f)
>>    print(f.__next__())
NORMAL LINE
```

However, as soon as I use a for loop, it seems that the parse() function is not called.

```
>>with open("myfile.txt") as f:
>>    for line in reader(f):
>>        print(line)
normal line
```

It's as if the for-loop was using the original **next**() method of my object instead of the overwritten one.

What am I missing here? I know I could achieve the same results in a simpler way, for instance yielding parsed lines in reader(), but I would really prefer to return this 'decorated' file object instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: changing methods on `file` instances is not likely to work; the interpreter notices in certain places when a built-in type is present and short-cuts some of the method lookups.  In the case of `dict`, which is designed to be sub-classed, it will do the "right" thing for a subclass that overrides those methods.  but `file` is not designed for that.  You're out of luck.

Comment: @IfLoop What you wrote is false. The *interpreter* does **not** "optimize away lookup on built-ins". It opimizes *all* accesses to *special methods* when they are called implicitly (e.g. in the `for` loop). However this is done for **all** classes, not just built-ins, so even subclassing `file` the code would work fine. What you are describing are other *functions* written in C that may have been optimized, but that is completely irrelevant to the question and examples at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a *huge* difference between your two examples. In the first one you are calling the `__next__` method explicitly, while in the latter you are letting the iterator protocol call it for you. In fact you can see that even in the first case the behaviour is not what you wanted:

```
In [5]: with open('myfile.txt') as f:
   ...:     print(next(reader(f)))   # next here calls the original implementation!
normal line

In [6]: with open('myfile.txt') as f:
   ...:     print(reader(f).__next__())
NORMAL LINE
```

You can see what the interpreter is doing by checking the bytecode using the `dis` module.
For example:

```
In [8]: import dis

In [9]: def f():
   ...:     for x in iterable: 
   ...:         pass

In [10]: dis.dis(f)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              14 (to 17)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (iterable)
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 16)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          13 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>   16 POP_BLOCK
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note how there is a call to `GET_ITER`, but no call to `LOAD_ATTR`. If you explicitly mention the attribute however:

```
In [11]: def f():
    ...:     for x in iterable.__iter__():
    ...:         pass

In [12]: dis.dis(f)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              20 (to 23)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (iterable)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__iter__)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            0 (0 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                 6 (to 22)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          19 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   22 POP_BLOCK
        >>   23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that `LOAD_ATTR` bytecode.

When you see a `LOAD_ATTR` bytecode it means that the interpreter is going to perform a full-blown attribute lookup on the instance (and thus finds the attribute you just set).
However bytecodes like `GET_ITER` perform a special method lookup, which avoids the instance attribute lookup.

When the interpreter calls the special methods as a result of a statement he does **not** look them up in the instance, but in the class. This means that he will *not* check the `__iter__` attribute you just created.

This is documented in some places. For example under [`object.__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__), which is the method used to implement attribute lookups, there is a note:

> Note: This method may still be bypassed when looking up special
>   methods as the result of implicit invocation via language syntax or
>   built-in functions. See [Special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup).

AFAIK, since files are written in C you cannot modify the attributes of the class, so you simply *cannot* achieve what you wanted.

However it's extremely easy to simply create a new wrapper class:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, fobj):
        self.fobj = fobj

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return parse(next(self.fobj))
```

An alternative would be to create a subclass of file. In python3 this is a bit complex to do because you have to subclass `io.TextIOWrapper`, where its constructor takes a buffer instead of a filename, so it's slighlty more involved than python2.

However if you did create a subclass *it would work fine*. There may be some problems when you pass its instances to some functions, which may decide to call the original file methods, however the interpreter itself would call the `__next__` and `__iter__` methods that you defined.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment. While waiting for an answer I somehow gave up (good thing I did!) and indeed used a wrapper class like the one you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying method of instances looks tricky to me, I would try to avoid that. If you just need kind of pre-processing the text file, you can do it in a separate function, like:

```
def preprocess(f):
    for l in f:
        yield parse(l)

with open("myfile.txt") as f:
    for line in preprocess(f):
        print(line)
```